# S3 data transfer from one account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I might be asking this again but need some help guys ,

I have a s3 bucket details from a client (Have the userID,Password,Access Key, Secret key ) . I have been asked to get all the data in there into our S3 bucket.

There seems to be a lot of data around how it can be done . But the problem for me is I don't have access to change any policy or anything from my end. I have a s3 bucket and a ec2 machine. Please guide me how I get this data from the above information to my s3 bucket

Comment: Do you have access to the source bucket? For example, can you use `aws s3 ls` to view the contents?

Comment: if you have username/password for the source s3 bucket and if your user has admin privileges on s3 you should be able to [follow this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-s3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `aws-cli` , then you can list all files using

```
aws s3 ls s3://your-bucket-name
```

and copy files from one bucket to another using

```
aws s3 sync s3://source-bucket s3://target-bucket
```

Thanks

Comment: Should I not get any settings to target the source S3 bucket or how do I connect to the source s3 bucket ? Please suggest

Comment: I tried to run the command but keep on getting the below error :Could not connect to the endpoint URL:

Comment: check this guide for aws-cli : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-using.html

Comment: @RaghunandanSk: can you post your command and the full error you got into your question?

Comment: @hansaplast 
 [ec2-user@ip-as-31-1assazz ~]$ aws s3 ls
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

This is the error we are speaking off

Comment: @RaghunandanSk I see, you run that in the ec2 instance. Is that already in the destination environment or in the source of the client?

Answer (score 0):

You may also use

`s3cmd cp s3://source-bucket/ s3://target-bucket/`

or if your buckets are in different region, you may enable **Cross-region replication** from the source bucket and specify your bucket as the target bucket.

Also, Important points to note when using **cross-region replication** are:

1. Versioning of the bucket should be enabled.
2. Versioning of both source and target bucket should be enabled.
3. This feature will only copy the new or updated files between the source and target bucket. If there is any existing file already in place between source and target bucket, it will not be synced.

If you still need that file to be copied again from the source to target bucket, you will need to use
 `aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/ s3://target-bucket` command.

Comment: Why are you saying that "versioning should be enabled"?

Comment: sorry, I have made correction to my post. version enabling is required for cross region replication (and not for sync). My apologies and thanks for correction..

Answer (score 0):

Since these are 2 complete different aws account, AFAIK you cannot use `aws cp` as you'll need two different credentials, one for your source and another one for the destination. Note of caution: You will lose all metadata (e.g. creation data, access rights, tags, ...) this way!

1. run `aws configure` and put in the access and secret key of your client
2. in an empty local directory run `aws s3 cp --recursive s3://client-s3-bucket .`
3. run `aws configure` again and put in your own aws credentials (destination)
4. from the same directory run `aws s3 cp --recursive . s3://your-new-s3-bucket`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot right, thanks! Forgot about that on. Added that to the answer